# How to align the Y-Axis of several JFreeChart based bar charts?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I try to layout a report in *JasperSoft Studio* (community). The data comes from a Postgresql Database. On my front page I want to plot three bar charts. The Layout position is always the left side of the page.

The issue is that the top chart have values on the Y-axis of 500,000 and the bottom chart only up to 60. The start of the Y-Axis is different on all three charts, depending on the Y-axis Label length.

How can I set an offset of the start of the Y-Axis, so that the value 60 has extra space on the left side and the three Y-Axis lines all on the same Y Position?

Here is a image of my problem:

[image]

Comment: Hello @AlexK , if I undersand Jasper correct, it should be generate by jFreechart. It is defently not the HTM5 lib.

Comment: Rather than adding `[resolved]` to the title, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0):

*The answer by @BjörnBeuck*

After some tries, the solution is as simple as possible. To align the axis, I work with a fixed size. The class to customize is this:

```
public class AxisAlignCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
        AxisSpace space = new AxisSpace();
        space.setLeft(50);

        if((chart.getPlot() instanceof XYPlot)) {
            XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getXYPlot();
            plot.setFixedRangeAxisSpace(space);         
        }
        else if(chart.getPlot() instanceof CategoryPlot) {
            CategoryPlot plot2 = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
            plot2.setFixedRangeAxisSpace(space);            
        }
    }
}
```

The main point is the function *setFixedRangeAxisSpace* of the chart. You have to notice that the function getXYPlot of the chart (param 1) can return also a *CategoryPlot* object.